# É possível utilizar o retorno de uma consulta com GROUP_CONCAT na clausula WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que busca o tipo de visibilidade que o usuário possuí, para então, buscar todos os outros usuários que ele "enxerga". O usuário pode enxergar todos os usuários da empresa, ele mesmo e mais um específico, ou todos da equipe a qual ele pertence.

```
WITH Q1 AS ( SELECT 
(CASE 
    WHEN v.is_completo > 0 THEN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN usuarios u2 ON u.empresa_id = u2.empresa_id WHERE u2.id = v.usuario_id)
    WHEN v.usuario_alvo_id > 0 THEN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM usuarios u WHERE id IN (v.usuario_alvo_id, v.usuario_id))
    WHEN v.equipe_id > 0 THEN  ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(eq.usuario_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM usuarios_equipes eq where eq.equipe_id = v.equipe_id )
END) AS id 
FROM visibilidades v
WHERE v.usuario_id = 440 ) 
SELECT u.id,u.nome FROM usuarios u where u.id IN (SELECT id FROM q1);
```

Para isso eu utilizei o `CASE WHEN` em conjunto com subquerys para tentar já buscar todos os usuários que ele tem visibilidade. O problema que essas subquerys, em sua maioria, retornam mais de um `ID` e por isso precisei concatenar.

Valor de Q1 = `[440,431,441,442]`. Porém ao tentar utilizar o resutado da consulta seguinte retorna somente o usuário da primeira posição (440).

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar esse arrays de `ID`s na cláusula `where IN` ou se tem outra maneira de atingir o resultado que procuro.

Comment: Mas a função GROUP_CONCAT não retorna uma string?

Comment: Sim. Porém não sei qual outra abordagem eu poderia adotar neste caso

Comment: Bom, se é uma string você não pode utilizar `IN`, talvez alguma das funções de string disponíveis no SGBD com que está trabalhando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas, acho que seria mais comum retornar os Ids dos usuários em linhas separadas na CTE para depois fazer a junção da CTE com a tabela de usuários, mas considerando o seu exemplo acredito que a CTE não é necessária pois a tabela de usuários já é utilizada nas consultas iniciais. Segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
SELECT u.id, u.nome
FROM visibilidades v
INNER JOIN usuarios u2 ON u2.id = v.usuario_id 
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.empresa_id = u2.empresa_id 
WHERE v.usuario_id = 440 AND v.is_completo > 0 

UNION ALL

SELECT u.id, u.nome
FROM visibilidades v
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id = v.usuario_alvo_id OR u.id = v.usuario_id
WHERE v.usuario_id = 440 AND v.usuario_alvo_id > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT eq.usuario_id, u.nome
FROM visibilidades v
INNER JOIN usuarios_equipes eq ON eq.equipe_id = v.equipe_id
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id = eq.usuario_id 
WHERE v.usuario_id = 440 AND v.equipe_id > 0
```

Espero que ajude